# "Missing \endcsname inserted" and other errors when trying to align title section

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, titlesec

I want to somehow align section headings: unnumbered should be centerized; numbered should be aligned left and indented. I'm just trying to compile an example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=15mm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section*}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
    \section*{РЕФЕРАТ}
\end{document}
```

But I'm getting

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
! Extra \endcsname.
! Argument of \ttl@assign@i has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \ttl@assign@i was complete.
! Package keyval Error: \let \reserved@d =*\def \par .
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
! Undefined control sequence.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
! Extra \endcsname.
! Undefined control sequence.
! Too many }'s.
! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRA unavailable in encoding OT1.
```

And - yes - is there a way to ONLY align sections not redefining a whole style? Should I use `\newcommand` instead and insert it in EVERY section?

Comment: What do you mean by "align a section"?

Comment: I want to centerize `\section*` title and make an indentation for `\section` title.

Comment: Should the change apply only to unnumbered sections or shoud it also affect numbered sections?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Unnumbered should be centerized. Numbered should be aligned left and indented.

Comment: @efpies please add this information to your original question. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `\justifyheading` command; you can use `\filcenter` instead; since different formatting will be applied to numbered and unnumbered sections, you can use the options `name=\section,numberless` in the first argument of `\titleformat` for unnumbered sections, and just `\section` for numbered sections. The `explicit` option was used to have explicit access to the title and to easily achieve the required indentation for numbered sections:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=15mm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\hspace{1.25cm}\thesection\hspace{1em}#1}% numbered sections
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1} % unnumbered sections

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text

\begin{document}
    \section*{РЕФЕРАТ}
    \section{РЕФЕРАТ}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, it works for the `\section`, but doesn't work for `\section*`...

Comment: @efpies please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works! And how I can indent a numbered section (with the number) by value defined in `\parindent`?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @efpies answer updated with the corresponding code.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to indent also subsections? I am adding the same line, but changed `#1` with `#1.#1`. And I am getting title as "1 LOLOLOL", not "1.1 LOLOLOL"

Comment: You will have to use something like `\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\hspace{1.25cm}\thesubsection\hspace{1em}#1}`
`\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}`.

Comment: Oh, I'm a sort of idiot. Should've replaced `\thesection` with `\thesubsection`, `#1` just prints title text and `#1.#1` prints it twice. Thanks a lot for your efforts and clarifying! (oh, you're answered me too)

Comment: @efpies yes, #1 controls the title and \thesubsection gives the counter.